# How to call JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sun_java_accessibility_AccessBridge_run

Tags: java

I want to call run method of the java access bridge.Please look the below method

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sun_java_accessibility_AccessBridge_run
```

https://github.com/apetrovskiy/STUPS/blob/master/binaries/accessbridge2_0_2/src/include/AccessBridge.h

Please let me know how call above API in my dll?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using eclipse?